# What kind of tools/techniques are used to reduce the thickness of metal tubing?

Tags: terminology

I'd like to be able to take some small brass or aluminum tubing, the kind sold to hobbyists, e.g., from [K&S brand](https://ksmetals.com/), and make it *thinner,* but maintain a cylindrical shape.

I presume a couple things here:

- There's a common tool (or set of tools) for this kind of thing, and maybe even a name for the technique (stretching? expanding?).
- Doing this kind of thing will increase the diameter of the tube, so if I have a target diameter in mind, I will need to begin with a smaller diameter tube.

**So, if I'm going to look for tools or learn the techniques involved for doing this sort of thing, what terms should I use?**

In case it's relevant, you should assume that I'm on a low budget and don't have much in the way of metal working skills.

Comment: Its called 'drawing'

Comment: What home improvement problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to experiment with making replacement ferrules for pencils.

Comment: Look up swage, it is something that may work for you. You can also build them yourself in you have the resources.

Comment: Just buy the right size. You could chemically etch to reduce wall thickness, but honestly the correct approach is to get tubing the size you actually want it to be. That might require so shopping beyond hobby shops, though a really good one would probably help you get it in if they did not stock that size. But really good hobby shops, like really good hardware stores, have suffered at the hands of alternative sources since cheap and low quality outsell not as cheap and better quality, with actual service. 0.5mm (standard mechanical pencil) ID brass tubing with 1mm OD $5-10+ship 0.5-2m long

Comment: "Doing this kind of thing will increase the diameter of the tube, so if I have a target diameter in mind, I will need to begin with a smaller diameter tube." - not necessarily, often in industrial settings the tube is made **longer**.

Comment: Had two sons who sid a toolmaking apprenticeship ie metal working. 3 weeks just learning filing so given your lack of skills be prepared to put in some time.

Comment: the ferrule that holds the eraser on wooden pencils?

Comment: @Jasen : Yes, the kind of ferrule that holds a pencil‘s eraser.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it on a lathe - a "watchmaker's" or "jewler's" lathe is likely the most suitable for this scale of work.

You can drill it out of solid stock. In the lathe, where you can also turn the outside to the diameter you want.

You'd have to invest in a lathe, and related tools, of course. And you have to learn to use it.

In a quick look at a typical wide-range metalworking supply, you can buy brass tubing off the shelf for $5-10 plus shipping (probably slightly more than the material unless you buy a lot at once) for half-meter to two-meter long chunks, with a 0.5mm hole in the middle and a 1mm outside diameter.  They also have stainless steel for $8-24 for the same sizes.

That one does not appear to stock 0.7mm, the other common pencil size, but somebody does, and it will cost less than buying a lathe.

If you want to make the wall of brass or aluminum tubing thinner, you can chemically etch it, but the process (like many processes) is more complex to get a uniform repeatable result from in real life than just "conceptually." Also, in real life you are left with toxic waste that needs proper disposal.

It would be easier to get a somewhat uniform result etching the outside of a plugged tube than to etch the inside of such a small tube at all. You'd pretty much have to pump etchant through, and you still might find an unacceptable degree of "the end it goes into is etched more than the end it comes out of" because the hole (and thus the volume of etchant inside) is so small that the etchant might be noticably weaker at the exit point.

Conceptually, you could draw it (pull it to deform it both longer and thinner.) Practically, I have doubts if you're not making a couple of miles of it, but you could look into jewelry techniques and tools (and gasp at the prices) for drawing on a less-industrial scale.